# Reset user password on reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, cron

Humor me for a moment because I'm aware that this is a terrible idea.
I'm trying to devise a way to reset a user's password each time the computer is rebooted.

So far, I've tried the following to no avail:

- Make a script to run `usermod --password CRYPTEDPASS username`
- Modify the root crontab to run that script `@reboot`

The other `@reboot` actions take place, but attempting to reset the user's password doesn't seem to work.  When I run the reset script manually, it works just fine.

Is there something I'm missing?
(Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?)

Comment: I just have to ask, what are you using this for?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out!

I had the grand idea to capture the output of the script running at boot.

Turns out it couldn't find the `usermod` command, so I changed the script to use the full path of `/usr/sbin/usermod` and now it works fine.